# cancel complete

Tags: autocompletion

Usually insert mode completion (`<C-n>`) inserts the right word the first time I press `<C-n>`, but not always. Therefore, I would like Vim to insert the match it deems best when I press `<C-n>`, but still allow me to cancel this insertion afterwards should the correct match not show up or be a long way down the list.

Of course I could code this behavior, but I have a feeling there should be a standard key(-combination) to do this. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Bonus question: is there another key I can use to get the longest match (as it was before I hit `<C-n>`)?

For what it's worth, I'm using `completeopt=menu`

Comment: Is `ctrl-u` what you are looking for?

Comment: No, ctrl-u seems to delete the entire line. I am looking for a combination that only removes the text that was inserted by pressing ctrl-n.

Comment: My first thought was "doesn't c-g the usual cancel key work here?", then I realised that was emacs. Just a few days of learning years ago has corrupted me, I shall bathe in a sacred river and purify myself!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From `:h complete_CTRL-E`:

```
                                                        *complete_CTRL-E*
When completion is active you can use CTRL-E to stop it and go back to the
originally typed text.  The CTRL-E will not be inserted.
```

Also if you, say, type `a` then `^P`and you get a very long list, you can hit `^N`
to return to your original text with the completion popup still active. You can then type extra characters to narrow the completion list.

Comment: That was precisely what I was looking for. I had not realized that ctrl-p would also take me back to the original input. Thanks.

Comment: @Octaviour, I find ctrl-p to generally be more useful than ctrl-n, because it searches for the closest match before (instead of after) where you are. So, if you have just written a word, ctrl-p would quickly show you the same word if you need to repeat it (for example using the same variable again in the code)

Comment: Yeah, I wrote `^P` out of habit for exactly that reason.